# Type assertion of returned value vs. typing function return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

What are the differences (if any) between [type asserting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) a function return value, versus [typing the function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#typing-the-function) return value in its signature type? Let's assume we are only talking about simple functions with a single return statement.

```
interface Foo { foo: number }

interface Bar { bar: Foo[] }

// type assertion
function buzz(foo: Foo) {
  return { bar: [] } as Bar;
}

// typing the function
function fuzz(foo: Foo): Bar {
  return { bar: [] };
}
```

See example [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.7.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN7JpgLmRAFcBbAI2mQF8AoO0SWRFAITih2Qs6I3QBtALq0GAenHIwATwAOKOAGcl0MMHQg6MEiATrNPEgC9jACnzp+mAJQ46yZFAhgSUEN15QiI2smXIHFAA3HT0dJLS8qAA5tIAFig6egZayfoaHjqmFoRotkRB9o7Oru6efMi+NKH0QA).

Comment: The former is potentially a lie (you could `return {} as Bar;`, for example), the latter actually allows checking of the return value type? Type assertions are useful where you have information the compiler doesn't, which *isn't* the case here.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was looking at the code in the playground and I thought you had it backwards. But it's just that the question text and the code don't align.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, none, since inference just types both `fuzz` and `buzz` as `(foo: Foo) => Bar`. You can see the difference i.e. if you try to add another `if` condition before the latest return, with a different return:

```
interface Foo { foo: number }

interface Bar { bar: Foo[] }

// type assertion
function buzz(foo: Foo) {
  // This changes the return type of `buzz` to Bar | object
  if (foo.foo > 10) return {};
  return { bar: [] } as Bar;
}

// typing the function
function fuzz(foo: Foo): Bar {
  // This is a type error, since `fuzz` expects a `Bar` as return type
  if (foo.foo > 10) return {};
  return { bar: [] };
}
```

In the first case, `buzz` is adapted. In second one, `fuzz` code throws an error.

The difference here is in the meaning: forcing `Bar` as return type means: "I'm declaring the output, so who will implement this need to respect the output, Bar".
Using `as Bar` as returns type tells: "ok, right now this returns an object but I'm sure the output should be a Bar. Anyway, whenever this change we should change the return type accordingly".